# Trying to get two dates, 24th of last month and 23rd of this month

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am trying to get two dates as variants so I can swap them in and out of an SQL query that runs every month (with different periods). I am trying to get the 24th of last month in `"yyyy-mm-dd"` format and the 23rd of the current month (when the procedure runs) in `"yyyy-mm-dd"` format. I have this code, but it is giving me 'wrong number of arguments' as error and I don't understand why.

```
Option Explicit
Sub mDateSet()
Dim fromDateFinal As String
Dim toDate As String
Dim toDateFinal As String
Dim fromDate: fromDate = Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Now), "yyyy-mmmm")
'Format gives 'wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment error'

'trying to define two dates: the 24th of last month until the 23rd of this month)

    '24th of last month
    fromDateFinal = fromDate & "24"

            Debug.Print fromDateFinal

    '23th of this month
    toDate = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm")
    toDateFinal = toDate & "23"

            Debug.Print toDateFinal

End Sub
```

Comment: If I run that piece of code it prints `2018-Februar24` and `2018-0323`. So you should add 2 dashes maybe to get a nice date formatting but it runs without any errors here. Cannot reproduce it. Are you sure that the code in the question is **exactly** the code you tried?

Comment: The issue was that as @Axel Richter said that `Format` was defined within the project, that's why I got the error. The code otherwise would have been (kinda) functional, that's why I didn't understand why is it giving me an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some string dates from manipulated dates and format masks.

```
fromDateFinal = format(date-day(date), "yyyy-mm-24")  '2018-02-24
toDateFinal = format(date, "yyyy-mm-23")              '2018-03-23
```

Comment: Thank you, this one seems much simpler than my code.  We had Format defined in another module so that mixed things up.

Answer (score 2):

If `Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Now), "yyyy-mmmm")` produces that error (`wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment error`) and does selecting `Format`, then there is another function `Format` defined somewhere in `<Global>`, which has less or more arguments.

Try `VBA.Strings.Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Now), "yyyy-mmmm")`.

`Strings.Format` is the fully qualified name of the needed `Format` function.

If it does selecting `DateAdd`, then maybe the same for this. There the fully qualified name is `VBA.DateTime.DateAdd`.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was exactly what you said. Multiple people are working on the same macro which controls SQL queries and I guess It never occurred to me that defining Format was the issue.

Comment: @Rhyfelwr: If it would be me, I would firing the one who has defined `Format` as a `Sub` or `Function` name in `<Global>`. At least screaming him into his face ;-).

Comment: @AxelRichter That is exactly one of the moments where you just want to silently stand up, walk out of the door for the rest of the day because you are in the mood to kill anyone entering your room.

Comment: the struggle is real